# RegEx Multiple Delimiters

Tags: regex, notepad++, delimiter

I have a text file with this format:

```
('1', '2', '3', '4', '5');
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
```

etc...

I want from each line the third and the fourth entry in the `''`

My Text file has 125k lines so it is something big.

Thank you

Comment: What do you want to do with it? What should the line look like after the replacement?

Comment: In the best case the line should like in the example above so:
3:4
c:d

Comment: This seems like an AWK problem.  http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm  <-- The AWK utility, by gnome.  then it should be something like `gawk "{ FS=\"', '\"; printf(\"%s:%s\", $3,$4); }" your_input_file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^.*?,.*?,(.*?),(.*?),.*
```

will get you the third and fourth fields in \1 and \2 (assuming no commas will appear between quotes, that you wish not to be treated as delimiters, or anything like that).

When run on your example, replacing with `\1,\2`, the end result is:

```
 '3', '4'
 'c', 'd'
```

Comment: Thank youuu very much i got it now but i have a second question all my lines begin with blabla. can i highlight or find any lines which dont start with blabla ?

Comment: You could replace `^blabla.*` with a blank line, and so eliminate what you don't want to find.  To explicitly find anything that doesn't start with "blabla", I believe you would need a lookahead, which I don't think Notepad++ supports.